# Does Spring JMS allow consumer priority?

Tags: jms, amqp, spring-jms, spring-amqp

I need to set consumer priority in a Java app consuming from an AMQP broker.

I want to use Spring JMS to set the consumer priority.

Broker-side, this seems simple; most popular brokers allow setting consumer priority ([ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/consumer-priority.html), [Qpid](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-broker-j-7.0.6/book/Java-Broker-Runtime-Consumers.html), [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html))

Consumer-side, Spring JMS only seems to provide for *message* priority via [setPriority()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#setPriority-int-).

Both Spring JMS and Spring AMQP have a class `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, but only Spring AMQP's implementation to allows for [consumer priority](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#consumer-priority) via [setConsumerArguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html).

I'd be somewhat surprised if Spring JMS didn't provide for consumer priority, but I haven't found any evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qpid and RabbitMQ we are talking about an AMQP protocol. The ActiveMQ priority sounds like a feature specific to this JMS vendor. There is no standard JMS specification for the consumer priority. That's why Spring JMS doesn't provide any consumer-based priority option.